# PHP-laravel for beginners level

Tags: laravel-4

After installing composer.I need to install laravel.I had given this command in command prompt-composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

After that given this command-composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

Again how do install laravel

specify any?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first step, in order to install Laravel you only have to run:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

And this will create a fresh copy of Laravel. You need to change `your-project-name` to the name of the directory in which you want laravel to reside.

Please be aware that Laravel is only a PHPframework, it is not an CMS like Joomla or a blog like Wordpress. You have to code everything yourself.

After the 'installation' or better said, downloading Laravel, you have to follow the steps in the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick.

Check (assuming you installed 4.2) http://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch for an introduction in laravel

Comment: after this command i donno to How to change project-name to the name of the directory

Comment: just delete the directory created with the wrong name, next run the command with the correct name for the project (just change `your-project-name` to whatever you like (without spaces). Or rename the directory like you always do with a directory on your server/computer.

Comment: how to see laravel installed successfully! how to do programs in that!as i am new to laravel tell me fully abt that! @MThomas

Comment: @BalaSubramanian I checked your other question, are you aware that laravel is only a php framework, it is not an CMS like Joomla or a Blog like Wordpress, you have to do everything on your own. After the 'installation' or better said downloading laravel you have to follow the steps in the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick. Check (assuming you installed 4.2) https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch for an introduction in laravel.

Comment: thanku.But how do i see laravel installed.i created my project name  as LaravelNewProject and how do i do programs!i dont get laravel in  my controlpanel-programs and features installed?do tell about this @MThomas

Comment: @BalaSubramanian You clearly don't understand what Laravel is, it is not a program you install on your computer, it is a bunch of PHP code put together to help you in creating websites. Check the link to Laracast in my answer and latest comment, watch the video's and then you might understand what Laravel is. Since it is not what you think it is.

Comment: i understand it but i cant see the feature of laravel.Thats y i asked again.where my demo project name is stored now?

Comment: It is not stored anywhere it is just the name of the directory laravel is copied into.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following into your terminal:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist "projName"
```

This command will create a folder with all the generated files you need.